# DataGrid column headers not aligned with data

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've got a DataGrid, which is quite simple as far as DataGrids go.  For some reason or other, the headers are not aligned with the rest of the data, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I've searched the internet but cannot seem to find a solution for it.  Here is my DataGrid code:

```
Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dgAttributes" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding itemsSource}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  CanUserAddRows="False" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                  CanUserResizeRows="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="False"
                  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Field}" Header="Fields"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn  Width="95" IsReadOnly="False" Header="Order" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortOrderProvider}}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SortBy, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding GroupBy}" Header="Group By"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="85" IsReadOnly="False" Header="Aggregate" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AggregateProvider}}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding AggregateBy, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding Having}" Header="Having"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding DisplayOrder}" Header="Display Order"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

It may also be worth mentioning that when I click on one of the Combobox cells, the headers align themselves properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are definitely having some style or something that is hiding the **top left** `Select All` button of datagrid. Hence the columns are shifted to left a little.

Use this thread to get hold of that button in `DataGrid.OnLoad` and check its `Visibility` property.

[Select All button WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817921/select-all-button-wpf-datagrid)

If its collpased/hidden, set the visibility to `Visbility.Visible`. Or check its `Width` being zero and set appropriate `Width`.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I defeated this problem
Find [the solution here](http://elashi.blogspot.com/2014/03/unaligned-column-header-with-data.html).

Sorry I did not notice you are not overriding the DataGrid control template. I am afraid , you will have to define a control template in order to correct the DataGrid behavior.

PS : I have .NET Framework 4.0

Answer (score 1):

I found that simply setting the **HeadersVisiblity** to **"Column"** does the trick - see XAML below. 
 Easier than getting hold of that `SelectAll Button`...

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" HeadersVisibility="Column">
```

Comment: Using this trick does not solve the problem, it just hides the row selection buttons. Instead of having one button missing (Select all), now you will have two.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the Property of the DataGrid Like and also define the particular css class for the Row

```
HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign=""
HeaderStyle-CssClass=""
```

Comment: My problem is with a WPF DataGrid though, not ASP.NET