# Datagrid rows not aligned with column headers

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the same problem as in this question:

[DataGrid column headers not aligned with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139615/datagrid-column-headers-not-aligned-with-data)

What I have is datagrid in my window but inside of scrollviewer. What I'm trying to do is to transfer my scrollviewer with this datagrid to another window. Now it works as good as it should but my datagrid is not aligned propertly in that another window.
What could couse this problem?
PS: let me know if you need any code to provide.

**UPDATE:**

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Name="inputReportScrollViewer" Height="22cm" Width="19cm" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >

<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <DataGrid Name="InputReportDataGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" >
                    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="Control">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="Control">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="RedniBroj" />-->
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="UCode" Binding="{Binding Path= tblGood.UCode}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Good Name" Binding="{Binding Path= tblGood.Name}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Measurement&#x0a; Unit" Binding="{Binding Path= tblGood.MeasurementUnit}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Path= Amount, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Input Price" Binding="{Binding Path= InputPrice, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Input Value" Binding="{Binding Path= InputValue, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Suggested Price" Binding="{Binding Path= SuggestedPrice, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Suggested&#x0a; Value" Binding="{Binding Path= SuggestedValue, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vat" Binding="{Binding Path= VatBase}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vat Value" Binding="{Binding Path= VatValue, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Suggested&#x0a; Value&#x0a; Without&#x0a; Vat" Binding="{Binding Path= SuggestedValueWithoutVat, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="RUC" Binding="{Binding Path= SuggestedValueWithoutVat, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the [HeadersVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.headersvisibility%28v=vs.95%29.ASPX) = None

Comment: post your XAML please .

Comment: @Stojdzaq You said that you've already tried that and it wasn't what effected your alignment .. so why did you except the answer ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to leave the comment. I had some bad bag, so I fixed it and it works. Acctualy i set HeadersVisibillity to "Columns". Thank you.

Comment: If you set `HeaderVisibility = None`, it only removes the header and does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom style for the column header

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
</Style>
```