# Multiple selection with checkbox using Datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, checkbox, datagrid

I would like to know how to select multiple rows with DataGridCheckBoxColumn .

Here I'm able to select only one row, but how to do multiple selection.

My XAML is as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="itemstyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGoldenrodYellow" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1" />
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEEEE" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Width="500" Height ="300">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Script}" HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionMode="Single" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" Background="White" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource itemstyle}" CanUserAddRows="True" GridLinesVisibility="None" Height="242" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  IsEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True"   Margin="10,14,0,44" Name="dgMain" RowHeight="23" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Width="478" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EditData}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Header="Select" Width="50" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Script_Text}" Header="Script" Width="400" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

thanks

SN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectionMode="Extended"` or `SelectionMode="Multiple"` will make your DataGrid multiselect

Comment: you are not able to select mutliple rows in DataGrid?

Comment: Yes, only one row can be selected !!
When I select the 2nd one, already selected item is  un selected :(

Comment: that is weird.. how are you trying to select the rows.. by dragging clicking and dragging mouse over rows?

Comment: I try to select by Click on the Checkbox. When click on the next row item, already selected item unchecked.

Comment: you IsSelectedProperty setter is hit when you check one checkbox?

Comment: when I select rows with Shift Key, multi slection is possible. not with one by one.

Comment: any solution guys me too "when I select rows with Shift Key, multi slection is possible. not with one by one"

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, credit goes to Scott

https://blog.scottlogic.com/2008/11/26/multiselect-datagrid-with-checkboxes.html

And the trick is to use RowHeaderTemplate like below

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
             <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                      AncestorType={x:Type dg:DataGridRow}}}"/>
          </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```