# How to style the select all button in datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a xaml datagrid definition, I have all my styles set up and all, but I don't know how to style that top left button in the corner of the datagrid which works as "select all" when you press it.

For example, I can style datagrid cells like this:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">...
```

So how do I style that select all button? Is there something like?

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridSelectAllButton">
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so if we go look at [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506248%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and do a quick page search there for "`the button in the upper left corner of the DataGrid`" we'll find `ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle` about halfway through that page, and at the top of their template examples.

I would suggest using Blend to tear down the parts of controls like this, sometimes elements can be pretty buried and it's pretty darn handy to be able to just right-click and keep editing your way through the templates until you find what you need instead of trying to do it blind which sometimes can be a real pain. Plus, checking the docs first should be the intuitive first thought.

Anyway hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Oh god, that style alone is longer than my entire application. I just wanted to change the background color of that tiny button. Is it possible to leave everything in that template at default an ONLY change the background color without having to include the Tokyo phonebook in my xaml?

Comment: It already exists in your application amigo, how do you think all your default stuff gets styled now?

Comment: Oh, and ya do know you're only looking at the top template right? And you could just target the `x:Name="Border` Not everything there in the example since that's all the templates for all the parts put together

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your resources:

```
<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This would seem to be the easiest approach, and I tried using it to place a "check all" CheckBox in the top left corner of the DataGrid.  Unfortunately, it seems the only way to enable the CheckBox is to set the SelectionMode property of the DataGrid to Extended, which may be impractical.  If anyone has a workaround, please share.